How can I stop a timer without using useState and useEffect?
In a simple timer component, I want to start and stop it with buttons, but the interval does not stop with a simple clearInterval function. Is there something I am missing?
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Timer3() {
    const [seconds, setseconds] = useState(0)

    let intervalId;

    const startTimer = () => {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setseconds((pre) => pre + 1)
        }, 1000)
    }

    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {seconds}
            <button onClick={startTimer}>start</button>
            <button onClick={stopTimer}>stop</button>
        </>
    )
}

I know that in the code above, there is a bug: if I press "Start" twice, it will count twice. I am going to fix this after finding out how to make it stop. There is also a solution on the web to use useEffect to run the timer, but I am not looking for code—just a simple answer as to why it does not work.

The issue is that each time the state updates it re-renders the component and the intervalId variable is redeclared and any previous value is lost, so when the stop button is clicked it doesn't have a reference to the running timer's id.
You can fix this by using a React ref to store the interval id value. React refs persist render cycle to render cycle.


function Timer3() {
  const [seconds, setseconds] = React.useState(0);
  const intervalId = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Clear any running timers when component unmounts
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    }
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    // Clear any running timers when re-starting
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);

    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setseconds((pre) => pre + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {seconds}
      <button onClick={startTimer}>start</button>
      <button onClick={stopTimer}>stop</button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Timer3 />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />




intervalId resets each time the component re-renders as its regular variable.
You can use useRef instead of useState and useEffect, useRef keeps the value and  do not re-render when changes.
const intervalId = useRef(null);
In startTimer, assign the interval to intervalId.current instead of just intervalId.
In stopTimer, call clearInterval(intervalId.current).

You can store intervalId in a ref useRef instead of re declaring it each time:
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Timer3() {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const intervalId = useRef(null);

    const startTimer = () => {
        if (intervalId.current) return; 
        intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds((prev) => prev + 1);
        }, 1000);
    };

    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId.current);
        intervalId.current = null; 
    };

    return (
        <>
            {seconds}
            <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        </>
    );
}

